# Trying to randomly pick a single element from a list and display it in C++

Tags: c++, list

I'm new here, and very new to programming, and for all the time I spent scouring the internet and this site, I can't seem to find an answer to this question of mine. I need to randomly pick a single element out of a list of characters and print it, and then repeat this a user-entered number of times. I'm trying to make a text generator for typing practice with individual keys, not words. (Yes, I know I am so very late to the "typing correctly" party, but my forays into coding made me see it was a more useful skill than I thought.)
So far, I have mostly found answers that use an iterator to print all the elements of a list in a row, which isn't what I want. I also keep coming across people saying to use a vector instead of a list, but my C++ book I started learning from doesn't go into a lot of things that are "too advanced", so I'm stuck there. Using a list seems like a good idea to me though, but it could just be my beginner-ness talking. An array would be too rigid for what I want to accomplish, because if the user could enter in the keys they want in a later version of this program, and not just code them in like I did for the first try, it would be more ideal.
But anyway, my program looks like this now:

```
// Version 1
// Text Generator for Typing Practice with Individual Keys:
//  For inputting into typing practice programs/sites with "insert your text" fields.
//   Generates a random list of letters from a list of known keys,
//    that only displays up to a user-entered amount of characters,
//     separated into paragraphs.

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main () {

//Declare variables used below
int x = 0;
int list_size = 0;
int p = 0;

// Add new letters to the list below as you learn them!
list <char> Keys_Known = {' ', ' ', ' ', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', 'e', 'r', 'u', 'i'};

// Define function(s) used below
char get_Text(); {
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; ++i) { // For x amount of times

            p = srand(time(nullptr)) % list_size;
            // Randomly choose a character from the list by its index,
            //  limited to the total number of elements in the list,

            cout << Keys_Known[p];
            //   and finally output the letter value of the index.
        }
    }

// Get and set list_size here
list_size = Keys_Known.size();

cout << "Enter total number of characters wanted: " << endl;
cin >> x;
// Set x to the total number of characters wanted in your practice text.
//  Maybe about 100 is good? ((Try with 10 for testing!))

cout << get_Text() << "/n" << get_Text() << "/n";
// Print two blocks of random text separated into paragraphs.

return 0;
}
```

I keep getting errors on the types of int p and int list_size not working with %, which is how I usually limit a random number range.  Eclipse also tells me that I can't say 'Keys_Known []' anything because it has no idea what [] is  supposed to mean. I even tried putting a 0 in there but it still acts like I can't use indexes. Am I missing an '#include' header?
The exact errors I get are:
"invalid operands of types 'void' and 'int' to binary 'operator%' line 29 C/C++ Problem"
and:
"no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list' and 'int') line 33 C/C++ Problem"

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: But srand is void function for initialization of generator. Use rand().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `std::list` is not a random access container. Hence, you may not use `Keys_Known[p]` to access an element.

   You may use an array or a `std::vector`.

   An array would work just fine for your needs.
2. There is lack of clarity in what you are trying to do -- at least the intention hasn't translated to code. It will be helpful to learn the fundamentals of the language from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Here's your code, updated and annotated. Hope it is helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main () {

   //Declare variables used below
   int x = 0;
   int list_size = 0;
   int p = 0;

   // Add new letters to the list below as you learn them!
   char Keys_Known[] = {' ', ' ', ' ', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', ';', 'e', 'r', 'u', 'i'};

   // Seed the random number generator.
   srand(time(nullptr));

   // Get and set list_size here
   list_size = sizeof(Keys_Known)/sizeof(Keys_Known[0]);

   cout << "Enter total number of characters wanted: " << endl;
   cin >> x;

   // Define function(s) used below

   // Incorrect.
   // This will execute the code in the loop x+1 times.
   // for (int i = 0; i <= x; ++i) // For x amount of times

   // Correct. Choose one.
   // for (int i = 0; i = x; ++i) // For x amount of times
   for (int i = 1; i <= x; ++i) // For x amount of times
   {

      // Get a random number mod list_size..
      p = rand() % list_size;

      // Randomly choose a character from the list by its index,
      //  limited to the total number of elements in the list,

      cout << Keys_Known[p];
      // and finally output the letter value of the index.
   }

   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are going on here:

As mentioned by Öö Tiib, the function [`srand(unsigned int)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) seeds the random number generator and returns `void`.  You should seed the random number generator once with `srand(unsigned int)`, then call [`rand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) to generate a random integer.

Second, [`list<T>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) is not a random access container, so unlike other containers, no `operator[]` is defined.  The documentation tells us that `list<T>` is implemented as a doubly-linked list designed to allow constant time inserts and deletes, but lacks direct access to an element at a given position:

> The main drawback of lists and forward_lists compared to these other
>   sequence containers is that they lack direct access to the elements by
>   their position; For example, to access the sixth element in a list,
>   one has to iterate from a known position (like the beginning or the
>   end) to that position, which takes linear time in the distance between
>   these.

You probably don't want to use a `list<char>` here anyway.  Some more efficient options would be:

1. [`vector<char>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), which does have a random access `operator[]` defined, and can be used as a drop-in replacement in your code;
2. [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), which is a container of `char`s that also has `operator[]` defined;
3. or just a plain old `char[list_size]`, which is all you really need here to get the job done, and is what I would recommend:  you don't need all the fancy iterators, search methods, or dynamic allocation that you get from using an std container.

Comment: Note that option (3) relies on variable-length arrays, which are not part of the C++ language (although they may still work, if the compiler the questioner is using supports them as a compiler-specific extention -- the code will not be portable though)